# Running a local kibana in a container

Tags: docker, kibana

I am trying to run use kibana console with my local elasticsearch (container)
In the [ElasticSearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) I see

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.2
```

Which lets me run the community edition in a quick one liner.

Looking at the [kibana documentation](https://www.docker.elastic.co/#) i see only

```
docker pull docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.2
```

Replacing pull with run it looks for the x-pack (I think it means not community) and fails to find the ES

```
Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/
```

Is there a one liner that could easily set up kibana localy in a container?
All I need is to work with the console (Sense replacement)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you want to use kibana with elasticsearch locally with docker, they have to communicate with each other. To do so, according to the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/#communication-across-links), you need to link the containers.
You can give a name to the elasticsearch container with `--name`:

```sh
docker run \
  --name elasticsearch_container \
  --publish 9200:9200 \
  --publish 9300:9300 \
  --env "discovery.type=single-node" \
  docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.2
```

And then link this container to kibana:

```sh
docker run \
  --name kibana \
  --publish 5601:5601 \
  --link elasticsearch_container:elasticsearch_alias \
  --env "ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch_alias:9200" \
  docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.2
```

The port 5601 is exposed locally to access it from your browser. You can check in the monitoring section that elasticsearch's health is green.

**EDIT (24/03/2020):**

The option `--link` [may eventually be removed](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) and is now a legacy feature of docker.
The idiomatic way of reproduce the same thing is to firstly create a user-defined bridge:

```
docker network create elasticsearch-kibana
```

And then create the containers inside it:

### Version 6

```sh
docker run \
  --name elasticsearch_container \
  --network elasticsearch-kibana \
  --publish 9200:9200 \
  --publish 9300:9300 \
  --env "discovery.type=single-node" \
  docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.2
```

```sh
docker run \
  --name kibana \
  --publish 5601:5601 \
  --network elasticsearch-kibana \
  --env "ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch_container:9200" \
  docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.2
```

### Version 7

As it was pointed out, the environment variable changed for the version 7. It now is `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS`.

```sh
docker run \
  --name elasticsearch_container \
  --network elasticsearch-kibana \
  --publish 9200:9200 \
  --publish 9300:9300 \
  --env "discovery.type=single-node" \
  docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
```

```sh
docker run \
  --name kibana \
  --publish 5601:5601 \
  --network elasticsearch-kibana \
  --env "ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch_container:9200" \
  docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.2
```

User-defined bridges provide automatic DNS resolution between containers that means you can access each other by their container names.

Comment: Why does ```--link elasticsearch:elasticsearch``` option is necessary?

Comment: Just to be clearer, I differentiated the container name from the alias. As both container are isolated, they can't send information to each other, this option enables a sort of bridge between them.

Comment: `ELASTICSEARCH_URL` env variable didn't work for me. I had to use `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS`. This is with Elasticsearch and Kibana version 7.6.2. Full example: `--env "ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch_container:9200"`

Answer (score 5):

It is convenient to use `docker-compose` as well.
For instance, the file below, stored in home directory, allows to start Kibana with one command:
`docker-compose up -d`:

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: "2"
 kibana:
    image: "docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.2"
    container_name: "kibana"
    environment:
      - "ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://<elasticsearch-endpoint>:9200"
      - "XPACK_GRAPH_ENABLED=false"
      - "XPACK_ML_ENABLED=false"
      - "XPACK_REPORTING_ENABLED=false"
      - "XPACK_SECURITY_ENABLED=false"
      - "XPACK_WATCHER_ENABLED=false"
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    restart: "unless-stopped"
```

In addition, Kibana service might be a part of your project in development environment (in case, docker-compose is used).

Comment: what are all the XPACK vars for?

Comment: These variables set respective parameters in kibana.yml, see documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/docker.html#environment-variable-config;
Xpack is installed by default in the official docker image.