# How Do i link the Sample Logstash docker container to the Sample Elasticsearch cluster on Elastics website?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, dockerfile, logstash

I was trying to do a quick bootstrap to see some sample data in elasticsearch.

Here is where you do a Docker Compose to get a ES Cluster:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

Next I needed to get logstash in place. I did that with: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/docker-config.html

When I curl my host, curl localhost:9200 it gives me the sample connection string.  So i can tell it is exposed.  Now when I run the logstash docker file from above, i noticed that during the bootstrap code it cant connect to:  localhost:9200

I was thinking that the private network created in for elastic is fine for the cluster and that i didnt need to add logstash to it.  Do I have to do something different to get the default logstash to interact with the default docker?

I have been stuck on this for awhile.  My host system is Debian 9.  I am trying to think of what the issues might be.  I know that -p 9200:9200 would couple the ports together, but 9200 has been claimed by ES, so I'm not sure how I should be handling things.  I didn't see anything on the Website though which says "To link the out of the box logstash to the out of the box elasticsearch you need to do X,Y,Z"

When attempting to create a terminal to the logstash server with -it though, it is continually bootstrapping logstash and isn't giving me a terminal to see what is going on from the inside.

What Recommendations do you have?

Comment: Have a look how it is done [here](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `--link your_elasticsearch_container_id:elasticsearch` to the docker run command of logstash. Then the elasticsearch container will be visible to logstash under `http://elasticsearch:9200`, assuming you don't have TLS and the default port is used (what will be the case if you follow the docs you refer to).

If you need filebeat or kibana in the next step, see this question I answered recently: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60122043/7330758

Comment: What does link do?  does it essentially give it rights to share data through a spoofed domain name?  Example:  in your case does `:elasticsearch` assign it as a domain name for reference in the `https://elasticsearch:9200` url?

Comment: Yes, imagine it's as an uni directional link cable between the containers. And you are right regarding the name, it simulates the hostname of the linked container. It's a old feature and it may be removed in future version. Have a look at docker networking for the up to date way of linking containers: https://docs.docker.com/network/links/

Comment: `link` is deprectated and should not be used. You should create a network and add both containers to this network...